Unresolved Reference Android Studio
I got a app I'm working on, however, I have been trying to solve an error for 2 days straight. It's an unresolved reference error, mainly in lines 27 and 25. Here is the code and screenshot. Thanks in advance.
package molotov.king.countermvvm

import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowScope
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
**import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel**
import molotov.king.countermvvm.ui.theme.CounterMVVMTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

**            val viewModel: CounterViewModel = viewModel()**
            CounterMVVMTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    TheCounterApp(viewModel)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun TheCounterApp(viewModel: CounterViewModel){

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement =  Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ){
        Text(text= "Count: ${viewModel.count.value}",
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Row {
            Button(onClick = {viewModel.increment()} ){
                Text("Increment")
            }
            Button(onClick = {viewModel.decrement()} ){
                Text("Decrement")
            }
        }


    }
}

The two bold texts are the ones giving me said error.
I tried asking ChatGPT(which I recommend not to rely upon the most for programming) to help solve this error, but it didn't help out. In the end, I still got the same error messages.
I was expecting the app to run smoothly after the fix had been applied to the code, but I still have a long ways to go.

If I understand correctly your app cannot find androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel?
If so perhaps you can double check if your dependencies are being fetched correctly. Perhaps add your build.gradle here too so we can check it.

Have you included the dependency?

@k314159, It was the dependencies. I added some new ones and it helped out. Thnx
